# PayPal Checkout Integration

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am hoping someone here can help me as I have been on to PayPal technical support who haven't been very helpful.

I am integrating PayPal checkout, following the instructions here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/

I wish to collect the paypal transaction ID in my database, send order confirmation emails etc... so as such I need to implement the optional step 5 described in this integration guide, which essentially means creating two routes on my server, one to call "create order" and one to call "capture order" - as per the sample code here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

I have got this working successfully however I wish to know 2 things:

1. How can I see the 3D Secure flow - PayPal tell me know to worry about it as they handle it within the popup window but I would like to see the flow. I have tried test cards that should invoke the 3DS flow but they dont show any 3DS flow, just complete the payment.
2. The response to the capture order end point can return multiple statuses (COMPLETED, APPROVED, VOIDED, PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED etc). Is it only the "COMPLETED" status that means a fully completed payment (and therefore I should complete the order)? What happens if it returns "PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED" - which means 3DS check needed - will PayPal handle this and then re-execute my route?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the normal, 'Standard' integration, you don't have to test 3DS. The PayPal page/iframe already takes care of everything about it.

[Only for the 'Advanced' integration -- where you are implementing individual hosted card fields with your own styling -- do you need to implement and test 3DS yourself]

---

PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED only happens with Advanced. All you need to do on the server end after the capture is check for COMPLETED and the existence of the Capture Id you're going to store for accounting purposes.

Comment: Hi @Preston, thanks for your response. I am aware that the standard integration deals with 3DS itself, but we would like to actually see the flow, and there seems to be no way to invoke that flow in the sandbox, paypal even sent me a list of card numbers but none work when using them within the demo: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: There is no need to test it in sandbox, since it is already implemented and has nothing to do with the things you'll be integrating. You can use a 3DS enabled card in production if you are that curious to see it.

Comment: Hi @Preston, thanks for all your help. One final question - this is for a french site and when the window opens for the user to log in, it is in english (goes to french after I log in as my french sandbox user though). I have tried adding locale=fr_FR (as mentioned here: https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/configuration/#locale) to the JS script tag as mentioned in the docs but this didnt change anything. Do you know how to force the language in that initial load of the login box?

Comment: locale=fr_FR will only change the language of the buttons on your site (otherwise the user's browser language is detected). The default language of the PayPal.com checkout page is detected from browser, cookies, or login -- not any locale you might have passed (that is only for the buttons on your site).